# Evaluate transpose: What is (X^T A)^T

Tags: calculus, matrices, vectors, transpose

$x, a$ in $\mathbb R^n$, $A$ in $\mathbb  R^{n\times n}$. I'm trying to compute $d(x^T A x)/dx$.

I got, in the last step: (x^T A)^T + Ax. Somebody said that this should equal 2Ax. Why is that?

[Resolved.]

Comment: In general, $(AB)^T = B^TA^T$.  So, you have $(x^TA)^T = A^Tx$ which in the special case of $A$ being symmetric, would simplify as suggested above.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to have been resolved (as per the newly added final line of post).